# Div position changed due to text wrap (css)

Tags: html, css

I have a layout like below to show pics and texts in individual divs.
**My problem here is that when the text is too long, the position of the div is changed** and looks not so nice.

For example, you may run the snippet below and **see the div with text "Trellis Combined Line Chart"**, you can find it's position is moved due to the too-long-text.

Do you have any solution for this issue? Many thanks!

P.S. I think styles you need to care below is only "pic_small_container", "pic_small" and "demo_illus".

```css
.overallPanel1 {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #BDBDBD;
    margin: 1.875em 0 3.75em 4.065em;
}

.pic_small {
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #BDBDBD;
    width: 12.5em;
    height: 10.4em;
}

.pic_small_container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 4em 4.375em 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.demo_illus {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    color: #3498DB;
}

.overview_page_title {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-left: 1.875em;
}

.overview_chart_title {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    
}

.picPanel {
    margin-top: 1.125em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chart Demo Overview</title>
    <link href="resources/demoStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div style="margin-top: 0.9em">
        <a class="overview_page_title">Demo Overview</a>
        <div class="overallPanel1">
            <a class="overview_chart_title">Trellis</a><br>
            <div class="picPanel">
                <div class="pic_small_container">
                    <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/line.svg"><br>
                    <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_bar">Trellis Chart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pic_small_container">
                    <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg"><br>
                    <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_stacked_bar">Trellis Stacked Bar Chart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pic_small_container">
                    <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg"><br>
                    <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_line">Trellis Line Chart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pic_small_container">
                    <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg"><br>
                    <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_pie">Trellis Pie Chart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pic_small_container">
                    <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg"><br>
                    <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_donut">Trellis Donut Chart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pic_small_container">
                    <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg"><br>
                    <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_combination">Trellis Combined Column Line Chart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pic_small_container">
                    <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg"><br>
                    <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_horizontal_combination">Trellis Combined Bar Line Chart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pic_small_container">
                    <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg"><br>
                    <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_bubble">Trellis Combined Bubble Chart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pic_small_container">
                    <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg"><br>
                    <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_scatter">Trellis Combined Scatter Chart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pic_small_container">
                    <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg"><br>
                    <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_area">Trellis  Area Chart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yes, use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and `overflow:hidden;` on a `<p>` element that will wrap your `<a>` elements. otherwise you could use `table` element  or if you don't care about old browsers you can use `flex-box`

Comment: Also, are you sure that's the correct way to use paddings? http://jsbin.com/lakevo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Do you have any suggestions for using padding? am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is your answer little change in css.

**Find the comment mentioned in css code**

```css
.pic_small {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #BDBDBD;
  width: 12.5em;
  height: 10.4em;
}
.pic_small_container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 4em 4.375em 0;
  display: inline-block;
  /*This will do the magic you want*/
  vertical-align: top;
}
.demo_illus {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  color: #3498DB;
  /* Overflow hidden. Width is only applicable to <a> if you add property display:block; or display:inline-block; */
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 12.5em;
  display: block;
}
.overview_page_title {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-left: 1.875em;
}
.overview_chart_title {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.picPanel {
  margin-top: 1.125em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chart Demo Overview</title>
  <link href="resources/demoStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin-top: 0.9em">
    <a class="overview_page_title">Demo Overview</a>
    <div class="overallPanel1">
      <a class="overview_chart_title">Trellis</a>
      <br>
      <div class="picPanel">
        <div class="pic_small_container">
          <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/line.svg">
          <br>
          <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_bar">Trellis Chart</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pic_small_container">
          <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg">
          <br>
          <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_stacked_bar">Trellis Stacked Bar Chart</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pic_small_container">
          <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg">
          <br>
          <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_line">Trellis Line Chart</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pic_small_container">
          <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg">
          <br>
          <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_pie">Trellis Pie Chart</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pic_small_container">
          <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg">
          <br>
          <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_donut">Trellis Donut Chart</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pic_small_container">
          <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg">
          <br>
          <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_combination">Trellis Combined Column Line Chart</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pic_small_container">
          <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg">
          <br>
          <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_horizontal_combination">Trellis Combined Bar Line Chart</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pic_small_container">
          <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg">
          <br>
          <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_bubble">Trellis Combined Bubble Chart long text for this div</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pic_small_container">
          <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg">
          <br>
          <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_scatter">Trellis Combined Scatter Chart</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pic_small_container">
          <img class="pic_small" src="resources/svg/horizontal_line.svg">
          <br>
          <a class="demo_illus" href="index.html?chartType=trellis_area">Trellis  Area Chart</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yep the vertical-align did works. I've tried to give a width to the text but it seems strange that there's an extra margin on the right of the text? May I remove it and let the text centered?

Comment: Well i use an inline-block instead of the block and it's perfectly fixed. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you do not really care about the old browsers like ie7 ie8, then you can make use of this.

Just update the below in your css.

```
.pic_small_container{
  ................
  ................
  max-width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: yes it also works, i've been trying to use a fixed width before, what i need here is vertical-align. thanks.